# Error on an ANSI SQL Statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, ansi-sql

```
select t2.s_studentreference
        , t1.p_surname
        , t1.p_forenames
        , t3.e_reference
        , t3.e_name
    from capd_a t1
    right outer join capd_b t2
      on (t2.s_id = t1.p_id)
    join capd_c t3 
      on ((t3.e_student=t1.p_id) and (t3.e_reference='D /YR2A2/12'))
```

I receive this error:

```
Syntax Error (Missing Operator) on (t2.s_id = t1.p_id)
        join capd_c t3 
          on ((t3.e_student=t1.p_id) and (t3.e_reference='D /YR2A2/12'))
```

Any idea what is wrong with my query?

Comment: I've just spotted that you are querying an Oracle database, I suggest moving to either an **ADO** recordset, or a **Pass through query**, you can then write the query in Oracle SQL (definitely nicer for the outer joins with the (+)) and also should massively improve the performance as the query will run server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try building your query in the Access query designer.  Coming from a different database system, you may not like the query designer much, but I'm suggesting you try it anyway because it will help you create SQL which the Access db engine can accept.

Among the differences you're facing are:

1. Access requires parentheses when your query includes more that 2 data sources, and is very demanding about their positions.
2. The db engine does not recognize JOIN as a synonym for `INNER JOIN`.  You must always specify the join type (`INNER`; `LEFT`; or `RIGHT`).
3. The engine will accept `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, but the query designer will change it to just `RIGHT JOIN`.  So it doesn't really make a difference, but I mentioned it only to avoid confusion.

If you can't tolerate the query designer, I'll offer this as a starting point.

```
select t2.s_studentreference
        , t1.p_surname
        , t1.p_forenames
        , t3.e_reference
        , t3.e_name
    from (capd_a t1
    inner join capd_b t2
      on t2.s_id = t1.p_id)
    inner join capd_c t3 
      on t3.e_student=t1.p_id
where t3.e_reference='D /YR2A2/12'
```

I user inner join both times because in certain situations Access balks with `LEFT` or `RIGHT` joins and `INNER` joins in the same query.  I'm uncertain whether your `RIGHT` join would be a problem in this case, but both as `INNER` will surely work.  So first get all the rest of the query syntax working correctly, then revise your join types as needed.

I moved `t3.e_reference='D /YR2A2/12'` from the `ON` to a `WHERE` clause.  That's my preference, but I don't think it will make a difference either way.

Answer (score 2):

Access has a pervert version of SQL and not the ISO/ANSI standard. It really likes (read: requires) parenthesis when joining more than two tables. There are also restrictions on what types of joins (LEFT, RIGHT, INNER) are allowed inside parentheses:

```
from 
   (                           --- required
     capd_a t1 
INNER join capd_b t2           --- RIGHT join turned into INNER
  on (t2.s_id = t1.p_id)
   )                           --- required
INNER join capd_c t3 
  on ((t3.e_student=t1.p_id) and (t3.e_reference='D /YR2A2/12'))
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried it but I receive a Syntax Error on FROM..... any idea what is wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you replace the `capd_a t1 right outer join capd_b t2` with `capd_b t2 left outer join capd_a t1` ?

Comment: No, that won't work either. Another restriction of Access. But the `RIGHT JOIN` is equivalent to `INNER JOIN` in this case. Because of the last `t3.e_student=t1.p_id` condition, the `RIGHT JOIN` is redundant, can be replaced with `INNER`.

Answer (score 0):

As your query includes `t3.e_reference='D /YR22/A12'` in `ON` statement scope which should be excluded from `ON` statement scope and write it seperately outside the `ON` statement scope......

You can do like this;

```
select t2.s_studentreference
        , t1.p_surname
        , t1.p_forenames
        , t3.e_reference
        , t3.e_name
    from capd_a t1
    right outer join capd_b t2
      on (t2.s_id = t1.p_id)
    join capd_c t3 
      on (t3.e_student=t1.p_id)
 and (t3.e_reference='D /YR2A2/12')
```

Or, you can do use `WHERE` clause in query:

```
 SELECT t2.s_studentreference
            , t1.p_surname
            , t1.p_forenames
            , t3.e_reference
            , t3.e_name
        FROM capd_a t1
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN capd_b t2
          ON (t2.s_id = t1.p_id)
        JOIN capd_c t3 
          ON (t3.e_student = t1.p_id)
     WHERE t3.e_reference='D /YR2A2/12'
```

Comment: with this, I still receive an error. Any idea? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks LolCoder for the update but unfortunately I still receive the error. I'm using Access to query an oracle DB using ODBC, maybe some problem with Syntax on ACCESS?? Many thanks!